# iPhone Application User Interface gets affected with ON CALL Notification

Tags: iphone, ios, user-interface, push, localnotification

I am developing iPhone application, my application user interface gets affected when there is call on my device.

i.e By attending the call, i am also using my application, at that time on call notification in green box appears at top of the screen.

when this notification comes, my application UI gets affected in pixels.

How to overcome this issue?

Regards, Balu

Answer (score 1):

You can use autoresizing property in UIView Class and test by toggle in-call status bar on simulator.